# How do I make a border padding for a UITextField?

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I see many Core Graphics questions here of course, so if this is a dupe, please forward me to the existing answer.

Inside a scroll view, I have some labels and textfields. The text fields have borders.

What I can't seem to figure out is how to make a padding between the border and the text.

You can see what's happening in this image:

[image]

This is the code snippet that's doing this:

```
roughDate = [[UITextField alloc] init] ;
        CGRect tempFrame = CGRectMake(125, 90, 300, 40);
        UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(4, 4, 4, 4);     
        CGRect roughDateFrame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(tempFrame, insets);
        NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(roughDateFrame));
        [[roughDate layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
        [[roughDate layer] setBorderWidth:1.0];
        [[roughDate layer] setCornerRadius:5];      
        roughDate.frame = roughDateFrame;
        [subview addSubview:roughDate];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use This:

```
_textField.leftView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 12, 20)];
    _textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    _textField.background = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:7 topCapHeight:17];
```

Comment: Ugh, I didn't think to manipulate the text itself. This worked, and I really appreciate your help.. (Final code: roughDate.leftView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 12, 20)];
  roughDate.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;)